# How to properly create a button with an image inside of it

Tags: ios, swift

Allow me to preface this by saying that I looked into different questions similar to this on stack overflow (and that i am a total novice to iOS/Swift), and they did help. However, my question now is as follows, actually 2.

The first one is whether or not it is possible to nest functions within the viewDidLoad method? When I try it as func createButton, then it doesn't even show two different new buttons, in fact it shows nothing except for the singular image I added via the storyboard.

Second question is what is the correct way to reference an image, because when I try to run my code I see the creation of two buttons which simply have a blue background. An extension to this is what is the correct syntax for the "action : " part of the button creation as I have no idea as to what is the valid way to reference your own function.

Code is below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var imageNames : [String] = ["dino2Button", "dino3Button"]
        var yposition : Int = 133
        let xposition : Int = 112
        let width : Int = 150
        let height : Int = 113

        //func createButton() {
            for index in 0...1 {
                print("index is: \(index)")
                let image = UIImage(named: imageNames[index]) as UIImage?
                let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect) as UIButton
                button.frame = CGRect(x: xposition, y: (yposition+10), width: width, height: height)
                yposition += height + 10;
                button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
                button.addTarget(self, action: "", for: .touchUpInside)
                self.view.addSubview(button)

            }
        //}


    }
```

And once again, I have been doing iOS for a grand total of two days.

Comment: Several things wrong here. First, maybe foremost - if you are barely two days into learning iOS & Swift (and you're doing good), consider taking the time **now** to learn auto layout instead of frames. Different devices have different frame sizes, and auto layout is very much worth it. Second, the reason you are seeing a blank/blue image is due to your UIImage being nil. Check your spelling, including case. Also, the only UIImage(named:) that work without a file extension is PNG (also case sensitive). If it's a .jpg, you need to add ".jpg".

Comment: Third, actions in addTarget are Selector type - so syntactically make is **#selector(myFunc)** and add a simple func that does something like **print("got here")** to make sure things are wired up correctly. Good luck!

Comment: @dfd thank you for the helpful pointers. Apparently my issue was that it was supposed to be button.setBackgroundImage instead of just .setImage; though it is possible their type may have been .jpg and not .png (i don't think i checked that yet). I will certainly look into auto layouts. Also, a quick side question, when developing for iOS is storyboard used more often for layout, or is it a balanced mix of storyboard and code? Cheers!

Comment: My opinion - and only that - is that it depends on the coder. Apple does a very good job with design time tools like InterfaceBuilder for auto layout, but, like virtually anything, understanding it (and sometimes knowing how to sink into code when needed) helps greatly. Either way, if you use frames (and many legacy coders still do) with iOS in particular, you'll soon run into the need to answer what happens when Apple introduces a new device size - and just today I heard the latest rumor about a 10.5 inch iPad. You want your iOS layout to work seamlessly across all sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to nest functions in the view did load as long as they are not performing asynchronous operations. If they are you have to be aware that you can't guarantee they will finish before your view appears. But other than this there are no real issues with nesting functions.

**EDIT: Check the apple [documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID178)**

To add images to your button it goes like this:

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox_off"), for: .normal)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox_on"), for: .selected)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox_on"), for: .highlighted)
```

To add an action to a button:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CheckBox.touchUpInside(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Where CheckBox is your class name (the one where the button is being placed at or any other you would like to call and the target is pointing at (in this case "self"))

```
func touchUpInside(_sender: Any?) {

    self.isSelected = !(self.isSelected)

}
```

Comment: Now, I was able to figure out the button action by doing the following: #selector(clicky(sender:)). As someone who comes from the world of Java where everything is a  class, what would my CheckBox class name be in this case? Also, is the way I am trying to set my buttons background image incorrect as it is showing it as just a blue screen.

Comment: Well i'll be damned, it was button.setBackgroundImage. All other answers i saw had it set as just button.setImage

Comment: Its either, but they do different things. The background image will let you have a text infront and as image as a background. The set image makes the image the actual button.

Comment: I see, because every time I set it back to just .setImage, it still only shows it as a blue screen. Is it possible perhaps that I may also need use something like scale to size or what not?

Comment: ensure your image is being retrieved correctly. (check for nil before setting it to the button)

Comment: Gotcha will try that soon, just somewhat strange to me that it works fine one way but not the other.

Comment: About the class name. Its actually your ViewController name. For example if your vc is for the home screen. The class that manages this screen should be called HomeViewController. (preferably)